# Does iPad or iPhone support OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

Does iPad or iPhone support OpenGL ES 2.0? How about iPhone os 4.0. Is this supported by the OS or the hardware?

And can anyone recommend some books on OpenGL ES development on iPad or iPhone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, iPhone 3GS, 3rd generation iPod touch, and iPad all support OpenGL ES 2.0 (e.g. shaders and programmable pipeline).

iPhone OS provides the required software APIs and dependencies and the hardware graphics chip supports the required functionality too.

Comment: Any recommendation for books?

Comment: @Siegfried: Not a particular one. If you're familiar with OpenGL, it's easy to get going with OpenGL ES with the docs.